# Removing non-printable characters with sed not working

Tags: unix, sed, ksh, non-printing-characters

I am working on AIX unix and trying to remove non-printable characters from file the data looks like  `in Arizona w/ fiancÃÂÃÂÃÂ` in file when I view in Notepad++ using UTF-8 encoding. When I try to view file in unix she I get  ^▒▒^▒▒^▒▒^▒▒^▒▒^▒▒

I want to replace all those special characters with space and my output should look like `in Arizona w/ fianc`

I tried `sed 's/[^[:print:]]/ /g' file`  but it does not remove those characters.My locale are listed below when I run `locale -a`

```
C
POSIX
en_US.8859-15
en_US.ISO8859-1
en_US
```

I even tried `sed -e 's/[^ -~]/ /g'` and it did not remove the characters.

I see that others stackflow answers used `UTF-8` locale with GNU sed and this worked but I do not have that locale.

Also I am using `ksh`.

Comment: Those characters are still "printable", maybe you meant `[:alpha:]`?

Comment: @Thor I can't see them on shell the appear as ^▒▒^▒▒^▒▒^▒▒^▒▒^▒▒^ on unix shell notepad ++ shows them when I change encoding to UTF-8

Comment: You need to upload a sample somewhere, e.g. pastebin, otherwise it will be hard to give a useful answer

Comment: @Thor I can't use pastebin blocked at my work network any other service you recommend?

Comment: Try googling for "pastebin alternative" there are plenty

Comment: What is your operating system?
Do you have a package like glibc-common installed?

Comment: Are you sure you tried `sed -e 's/[^ -~]//g' file > newfile`? It must work if the chars you want to remove are outside the SPACE-TILDE char range. Maybe `LANG=C sed -e 's/[^ -~]//g' file > newfile` will work (though it seems redundant). Try `awk '{gsub(/[^ -~]/,"",$0)}1' file > newfile`, too.

Answer (score 0):

### Easiest - `strings`

Easiest way to do this is with the `strings` command:

```
$ cat  /tmp/asdf
in Arizona w/ fiancÃÂÃÂÃÂ
$ strings  /tmp/asdf
in Arizona w/ fianc
```

The problems with this approach:

- It's not using sed
- It adds an end of line whenever it finds any non-printable character (it should be ok in your example, as they're all grouped at the end, but it will fail otherwise)

### Ugliest - `sed`'s `l` plus `sed` post-processing

Now, if you must use `sed`, then here's an alternative:

```
$ sed -n l /tmp/asdf | sed -E 's/\\[[:digit:]]{3}//g; s/\$$//'
in Arizona w/ fianc
```

Here, you're using `l` to 'dump' non-printable characters, transforming them into octal representations like `\303`, then removing anything that looks like an octal value so created, and then removing the `$` that `l` added at the end of the line.

It's kinda ugly, and may interact badly with your file, if it has anything which starts with a backslash followed by three digits, so I'd stay with the `strings` option.

### Better - `sed` ranges with high Unicode characters

The one below is also a hack, but looks better than the rest.  It uses `sed` ranges, starting with '¡'.  I picked that symbol because it is the second* character in the iso-8859-1 encoding, which also happens to be the Unicode section right after ASCII.  So, I'm guessing that you're not having trouble with actual control codes, but instead of non-ASCII characters (anything represented over 127 Decimal).

For the second item in the range, just pick some non-latin character (Japanese, Chinese, Hebrew, Arabic, etc), hoping it will be high enough in Unicode that it includes any of your 'non-printing' characters.

Unfortunately, `sed` does not have a `[[:ascii:]]` range.  Neither it accepts open-ended ranges, so you need this hack.

```
$ sed 's/[¡-ﺏ]/ /g' /tmp/asdf
in Arizona w/ fianc
```

**(*)** Note: I picked the second character in the range because the first character is a non-breaking space, so it would be hard to understand that it is not just a normal space.